# Cocos2d Selector with multiple args

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Lets say i wanna call a cocos2d method after 2 seconds, like this:

```
[self runAction:[CCSequence actions:
                     [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:2],
                     [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:[GameScene sharedScene] selector:@selector(GameOverAndLost:) withObject:TRUE],
                     nil]];
```

i'm trying to send a BOOL to that method, but somehow that doesn't seam to be the way

```
- (void) GameOverAndLost:(BOOL)bol
```

Anyone know's what i'm doing wrong here? this is quite a simple task, but i'm really not that used to ObjC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One mistake in your code: Used CCCallFunc instead of CCCallFuncN. (CCCallFunc not takes any argument).

```
        [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(GameOverAndLost:)];
```

To send multiple argument, better go for CCCalBlockN.

```
id calFun = [CCCallBlockN actionWithBlock:^(CCNode* node) 
    {
        //control comes here when block is executed...
        //here you can access class member variables and variables in same function
    }
    ];
```

Comment: it still doesnt seam to work, i tried this:

                         [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget:[GameScene sharedScene] selector:@selector(GameOverAndLost:) data:@"dostuff"],

and it doesnt crash anymore, but the problem is that if i NSLog what im receiving.. i get nothing

Comment: syntax wrong, [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(GameOverAndLost:data:) data:@"dostuff"]; also write function -(void) GameOverAndLost:(id)sender data:(void *)data  in GameScene.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573257/cocos2d-passing-a-cgpoint-through-cccallfuncnd

Comment: also checkout this: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/having-trouble-passing-an-argument-to-cccallfuncnd/